# fmt.Scanf not working properly in Go

Tags: go, scanf

I'm trying out a snippet that is supposed to test out fmt.Scanf, but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("What is your favorite color?")
    var favoriteColor string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &favoriteColor)
    fmt.Println("Fave color is", favoriteColor)
    fmt.Println("What is your favorite food?")
    var myfood string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &myfood)
    fmt.Printf("I like %s too!\n", myfood)
    fmt.Printf("Wait two seconds please...\n")
    time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("Your favorite color is %s, and the food you like best is %q\n", favoriteColor, myfood)
}
```

However only the first answer is taken, the program continues to the end and then returns:

```
What is your favorite color?
red
Fave color is red
What is your favorite food?
I like  too!
Wait two seconds please...
Your favorite color is red, and the food you like best is ""
```

Why is the second scanf function being ignored?  It makes no sense to me.

I installed Go using the most recent 64bit package on Windows 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put a `\n` after the `%s` so it consumes the newline you type. Otherwise the newline goes into the next scan.

Comment: I could tell the newline was going into the next scan, thanks for showing me this.

Comment: exactly.. coming from a C++ background, i am familiar with this

Comment: @AceixSmart Actually`fmt.Scanf` behaves slightly differently than C `scanf` in the way it treats newlines.  Refer to the documentation for details.