# How can I scan a rune?

Tags: go, rune

So far, I haven't been able to print a rune by scanning it with `fmt.Scan` and printing it with `fmt.Print`. This is the vary basic code I'm working on:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var c rune
    fmt.Scan(&c)
    fmt.Printf("%c", c)
}
```

But it doesn't work, in fact, `Printf` doesn't produce any output. Instead, by manually assigning a char to my variable c (like `var c rune = 'a'`, without using `fmt.Scan`), I'm able to print the wanted rune. How can I scan a rune?

Comment: A `rune` is an integer value, check the count and error from `fmt.Scan`

Answer (score 1):

It seems `Scan()` cannot read `rune` (†1). Use `Scanf("%c", &c)` instead.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var c rune
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%c", &c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%c", c)
}
```

†1: I don't know why but perhaps the core team decided to do so as `rune` is internally just an integer type.

Answer (score -3):

As we know `Scan` return n and err so please check for error under `Scan` statement as follows

```
n, err := fmt.Scan(&c)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

It will clearly show you the error and why it was ignored.

Other than the above, please try it locally on your own laptop instead of the playground because on the playground it most of the time gives an `EOF` error as most of them do not support reading from the terminal.

I hope the above helps you in debugging the issue.

Other Reference:

[Scanf ignores if not provided \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536746/fmt-scanf-not-working-properly-in-go)

Comment: The error being what, and why does it show that error?

Comment: This doesn't answer _How to print the scanned rune_